# Can I fit a Weibull distribution on both positive and negative values (observations)?

Tags: distributions, weibull-distribution

I have dataset with observations having both positive and negative values. I would like to know if I can check if my dataset follows a Weibull distribution.

Comment: Obviously you do not mean the usual [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), which applies only to positive values by definition.  What generalization do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic two-parameter [Weibull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) pdf is

$$ f(x;\lambda,k) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}e^{-(x/\lambda)^{k}} & x\geq0 ,\\
0 & x<0.
\end{cases} $$

so it's support is non-negative. The story behind it is that $x$ is time-to-failure and $k$ is change of failure rate over time, so $x$ cannot be negative.

However it [can be parametrized](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3668.htm) also by an additional location parameter $\mu$, then it's pdf becomes

$$ f(x;\lambda,k,\mu) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}e^{-(\frac{x-\mu}{\lambda})^{k}} & x\geq \mu ,\\
0 & x < \mu.
\end{cases} $$

In such case negative values (for $\mu<0$) are possible, but you need to define the lower limit of the distribution. Because of that it is not the best choice for values that can be negative.

Comment: It is a bit tricky, I have a dataset with continuous values that are both positive and negative but they do not however follow a normal distribution for according to the qq plot. What are the options I could have for my case study? as i know that it can not be lognormal or exponential or gamma as they are only for positive observations.

Comment: @user3841581 You seem to be asking a new question (and should probably post it as one). You'll need to give more information for it to be answerable, though -- things like: What are you measuring? What does your qq-plot look like? What made you ask about the Weibull? Why do you need to identify a distribution at all --  what are you trying to use it for?

Answer (score 1):

The [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) is only defined for x ≥ 0. So you would have so transform your data before trying to fit a Weibull distribution. But it depends on your data if that is feasible. It might be better to look at other distributions.